# Why does the C runtime on Mac OS allow both precomposed and decomposed UTF-8?

Tags: c, macos, utf-8, posix

So we all know that the filesystem on Mac OS has this wacky feature of using fully decomposed UTF-8. If you call POSIX APIs like `realpath()`, for example, you'll get such a fully decomposed UTF-8 string back from Mac OS. When using APIs like `fopen()`, however, passing precomposed UTF-8 seems to work as well.

Here is a little demo program which attempts to open a file named `ä`. The first call to `fopen()` passes a precomposed UTF-8 string, the second call passes a decomposed UTF-8 string and to my surprise both work. I'd expect only the second one to work but precomposed UTF-8 works as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp, *fp2;

    fp = fopen("\xc3\xa4", "rb");       // ä as precomposed UTF-8
    fp2 = fopen("\x61\xcc\x88", "rb");  // ä as decomposed UTF-8

    printf("CHECK: %p %p\n", fp, fp2);

    if(fp) fclose(fp);
    if(fp2) fclose(fp2);

    return 0;
}
```

Now to my questions:

1. Is this defined behaviour? i.e. is it allowed to pass precomposed UTF-8 to POSIX APIs or should I always pass decomposed UTF-8?
2. How can functions like `fopen()` even know whether the file passed contains precomposed or decomposed UTF-8? Couldn't this even lead to all sorts of issues, e.g. wrong files being opened because the passed string can be interpreted in two different ways and thus potentially point to two different files? This is somewhat confusing me.

***EDIT***

To make the confusion complete, this weird behaviour doesn't even seem to be limited to file I/O. Take a look at this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("\xc3\xa4\n");
    printf("\x61\xcc\x88\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Both `printf` calls do exactly the same, i.e. they both print the character `ä`, the first call using precomposed UTF-8 and the second one using decomposed UTF-8. It's really weird.

Comment: I *assume* that the path is always decomposed on the HFS+ file system level, so it does not matter what you pass in.

Comment: The file system is also case insensitive, isn't it? This would be the same as passing the wrong case letters to `fopen`. The internal mechanism to search for a filename probably handles both cases the same way.

Comment: But what did `readdir` return?

Comment: @EdwardThomson: As I wrote in my original posting, POSIX APIs all return decomposed UTF-8. `readdir()` is no exception here.

Comment: @MartinR: I still don't understand this. Isn't it possible in this case that the string passed to `fopen()` matches two different files? How does `fopen()` choose a file then?

Comment: @Andreas: fopen() does not "choose a file". It passes the file name to the open() system call which in turn passes the file name to the file system. The file system does whatever is necessary to find and open the file. In the HFS+ case, the file name is normalised (decomposed). If successful, a file descriptor is passed back.

Comment: @MartinR: I don't really care who chooses the file in the end. The main issue I was trying to describe is this: Can't it happen that a string passed to fopen() describes two different files depending on whether the string is interpreted as precomposed UTF-8 or decomposed UTF-8? I don't know much about the internals of precomposed vs. decomposed UTF-8 so I can't tell. I was just wondering if this could happen in theory because AFAICS there's no reliable way for the file system to tell whether the string it got from fopen() or open() or whatever is precomposed or decomposed UTF-8...

Comment: @MartinR: Behaviour doesn't seem limited to HFS+ interactions. It even happens with standard printf calls to stdout. See my edits in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There're two different types of equivalence in Unicode strings: One thing is *canonical equivalence*, and another is *compatibility*. Since your question is about strings that seem to be considered identical by the software, let's focus in **canonical equivalence** (OTOH, *compatibility* allows for semantic differences, so it's off-topic in this question).

Citing from [Unicode equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence) in Wikipedia:

> Code point sequences that are defined as **canonically equivalent** are
>   assumed to have the same appearance and meaning when printed or
>   displayed. For example, the code point U+006E (the Latin lowercase
>   "n") followed by U+0303 (the combining tilde "◌̃") is defined by
>   Unicode to be canonically equivalent to the single code point U+00F1
>   (the lowercase letter "ñ" of the Spanish alphabet). **Therefore, those
>   sequences should be displayed in the same manner, should be treated in
>   the same way by applications such as alphabetizing names or searching,
>   and may be substituted for each other**.

In other words, if two strings are **canonically equivalent**, the software should consider the two strings **represent exactly the same thing**. So, MacOS is doing the correct thing here: You have two different UTF-8 strings (one decomposed, another precomposed), but they are **canonically equivalent**, so they map to the same object (the same file name in your example). That's correct (remember the *"should be treated in the same way by applications such as alphabetizing names or searching, and may be substituted for each other"* line in the quote above).

I don't really understand your second example about `printf()`. Yes, both a decomposed character and a precomposed character render the same output. That's precisely the point in the dual representation of characters supported by Unicode: You can choose whether to represent a combined character with a precomposed sequence of bytes, or a decomposed sequence of bytes. They print the same visual result, but their representation is different. If both representations are **canonically equivalent** (in some cases they are, in some cases they are not), then the system must consider them as two representations of the same object.

In order to manage all of this more comfortably in your software, you should [normalize your Unicode strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normalization) before working with them.