# MacOS Big Sur: unexpected diff behaviour

Tags: utf-8, macos-big-sur

On MacOS Big Sur (Intel), I see the following unexpected behaviour, that I have not seen on Catalina. Prerequisites.

1. My home directory /Users/foo resides on an afps-filesystem.
2. /mnt/win10 is an SMB share mounted from a Win 10-machine (20H2).

When I have a file where the filename contains unicode characters that can have more than one representation ([precomposed vs decomposed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38484369/why-does-the-c-runtime-on-mac-os-allow-both-precomposed-and-decomposed-utf-8)) , the representation will change when copying the file from one filesystem to the other.

```
touch /Users/foo/ä
cp /home/user/ä /mnt/win10/.
```

Then `diff /Users/foo/ä /mnt/win10/ä` shows no differences but `diff /Users/foo/. /mnt/win10/.` will rather unexpectedly result in:

```
Only in /Users/foo/.: ä
Only in /mnt/win10/.: ä
```

Checking the encoding using a bit of Perl in the following script (call with `./script.pl /Users/foo/. /mnt/win10/.'):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use String::Dump qw( dump_hex dump_bin );

while (my $d = shift) {
    opendir(D, "$d") || die "Can't open directory $d: $!\n";
    my @list = readdir(D);
    closedir(D);

    foreach my $f (@list) {
         print "\$f = $f\n";
         print dump_hex($f);
         print "\n";
     }
}
```

will give the rather unexpected result for the afps-filesystem /Users/foo

```
$f = ä
C3 A4
```

and for the SMB share /mnt/win10

```
$f = ä
61 CC 88
```

So on the afps, we see the precomposed UTF-8 representation of 'ä', while on the SMB share, we find the decomposed UTF-8 representation (a small 'a' to be combined with two dots).
I have never encountered this with Catalina (but have not checked this for a while), I cannot find any documentation of a changed behaviour.
Needless to say that this obviously breaks things (Apple provided diff 2.8.1, homebrew provided diff 3.7). rsync 3.2.3 can work around this when you call it with `--iconv=utf-8-mac,utf-8-mac` (sic!).
I have my own personal opinion if an OS should behave like that.
What is the proper approach to handle this in a POSIX compliant manner?
Should I convert every filename with iconv(3) to utf-8-mac?

Comment: is your `LANG=` changes? Or maybe you changed the shell some time ago, and you never tested with zsh. POSIX? I think they never ruled about this: complex (one user may be in a different locale then an other, and UTF-8 as first citizen is "modern"). OTOH Unicode requires that Unicode aware programs must interpret canonical equivalent as equivalent, so it seems `diff` is to blame.

Comment: How did you create that filesystem object named `ä` (_Latin Small Letter A_ + _Combining Diaeresis_) inside `/mnt/win10/`?

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: LANG is de_DE.UTF-8 and I have not changed it. Same with the shell, I have started only with Catalina, so zsh has always been my shell.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Canonical equivalent, how would I test that in a POSIX-C programm on Big Sur? Using iconv(3) when comparing filenames? Edited Question.

Comment: @JosefZ: See above, copying with `cp /Users/foo/ä /mnt/win10/.`

Comment: I do not know. I use programming language (many of them can do it). But I cannot find a good way to do command line. Which it is something worrying